# react-native Navigator (navbar) Hiding View Under Navbar

Tags: react-native

I'm having a hard time figuring out which props I need to change in the initial view below the Navbar. Or is there a prop for the navbar I need to change? Basically, the navbar is hiding the top portion of the underlying view. I'm attaching a screen cap here:

[image]

Here is my code.

Navigator code:

```
var routeMapper = {
  LeftButton: function(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    if(index > 0) {
      return (
        <TouchableHighlight
          underlayColor="transparent"
          onPress={() => { if (index > 0) { navigator.pop() } }}>
          <Text style={ styles.leftNavButtonText }>Back</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>)
    }
    else { return null }
  },
  RightButton: function(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return null;
  },
  Title: function(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return <Text style={ styles.navbarTitle }>EST4Life</Text>
  }
};

module.exports = React.createClass({


  renderScene: function(route, navigator) {
    var Component = ROUTES[route.name]; // ROUTES['signin'] => Signin
    // return the component with props to the current route and the navigator instance
    return <Component route={route} navigator={navigator} />;
  },

  render: function() {
    // return an instance of Navigator
    return (
      <Navigator

        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{name: 'signin'}}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        configureScene={() => { return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight; }}
        navigationBar={<Navigator.NavigationBar
          routeMapper={routeMapper}
          style={styles.navBarStyle}
        />}
      />
    )
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  navBarStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
    flex: 1,
    borderWidth: 1
  },
  navbarTitle: {
    color: 'white',
  },
  rightNavButtonText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
  leftNavButtonText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
})
```

signin.js

```
module.exports = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    if (this.state.user == '') { // this.state.user = '' when signin is initiated
      return <View style={styles.container}><Text>Loading...</Text></View>
    } else if (this.state.user == null){ // this.state.user == null when user is not logged in
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <Text>Sign In</Text>

            <Text style={styles.label}>Username:</Text>
            <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            value={this.state.username}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({username: text})}
            />

            <Text style={styles.label}>Password:</Text>
            <TextInput
            secureTextEntry={true}
            style={styles.input}
            value={this.state.password}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
            />

            <Text style={styles.label}>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>
            <Button text={'Sign In'} onPress={this.onLoginPress} />
            <Button text={'I need an account..'} onPress={this.onSignupPress} />

        </View>
      ); // onPress={this.onPress} - pass in the onPress method below to TouchableHighlight
    } else { // clear view when user is logged in
      return <View><Text></Text></View>
    }

  }, // end of render



var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 4,
    borderColor: 'green'
  },
  input: {
    padding: 5, // space between text and inside of box
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    margin: 5,
    width: 200,
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 18
  }
});
```

Thanks.

Update: I figured out how to extract the heights involved with the navbar.
Code for use where the component is created:

```
var NavBarHeight = navigator.props.navigationBar.props.navigationStyles.General.NavBarHeight
var StatusBarHeight = navigator.props.navigationBar.props.navigationStyles.General.StatusBarHeight
var TotalNavHeight = navigator.props.navigationBar.props.navigationStyles.General.TotalNavHeight
```

Code to use in any scene thereafter:

```
var NavBarHeight = this.props.navigator.props.navigationBar.props.navigationStyles.General.NavBarHeight
var StatusBarHeight = this.props.navigator.props.navigationBar.props.navigationStyles.General.StatusBarHeight
var TotalNavHeight = this.props.navigator.props.navigationBar.props.navigationStyles.General.TotalNavHeight
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your `signin.js` `container` some `marginTop`. That will get it done.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Will that value need to change or be different based on each device resolution and/or density? Or does RN do that automagically?

Comment: I would expect it to change. there's nothing automagical as far as I know.

Comment: In my experience, it's 64 for iOS and 50-something for Android by default.

Comment: @Kevin - Thanks. Also, I just learned that I have control over the height of the navbar using styles. So, I'll probably just assign the navbar height a number close to what you're suggesting and use that same number as my marginTop for the underlying view. Thanks fellas! PS. How can I extract the height property of the navbar? Navigator.navbar.height?

Comment: NavBarHeight = navigator.props.navigationBar.props.navigationStyles.General.NavBarHeight, StatusBarHeight = navigator.props.navigationBar.props.navigationStyles.General.StatusBarHeight, TotalNavHeight = navigator.props.navigationBar.props.navigationStyles.General.TotalNavHeight

Comment: 44, 24, 64, respectively for iphone6 simulator.

Comment: The code in the comment above can be used where the component is created. To get the same info in any scene thereafter, put this.props. in front of the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using sceneStyle for navigator? This applies to every scene being rendered using this navigator. So you can try something like { marginTop: 55 } and adjust from there based on the height of your navigation bar.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#scenestyle

Comment: Just looked at your code again, The Navigator component shouldn't have a style prop. So, try changing that to sceneStyle with the marginTop.

Comment: The code I added in my "update" in my original post works for me. I'll give yours a try also and report back.